# When asked to write function for multiple of 3, why do i keep getting errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

When I'm asked to write in my function a code to count the characters of a code but only if its a multiple of three, i keep getting stuck and i've tried so many times to figure it out but to no avail!
This was the question: ...verifies that its length is a multiple of 3, and returns the number of codons in that string...

I tried this:

```
def countCodons(DNA):
  count = 0
  for num in DNA:
    if len(num) % 3 == 0:
      count += 1
      return len(DNA)
    else:
      return False
assert countCodons("CATGGG") == 2
assert countCodons("CAATGGG") == False
```

But I keep getting an error. When i just put in "countCodons" I keep getting False.

Comment: _But I keep getting an error_ Are we supposed to guess what the error is?  Show us.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop here.

Comment: Your `for` loop is pointless, since you *always* return on the first iteration (which is almost certainly a bug).  You never look at anything past the first element of `DNA`.  If it's a multiple of 3, you return `len(DNA)`.  Otherwise you return `False` (which also makes no sense - you're mixing integer and bool return values).  Also, `count` serves no purpose whatsoever.  It is set, and incremented, but otherwise unused.  Try to think about what you're doing.  This isn't a language issue, it's just basic reasoning.

Comment: So I don't need a for loop, but I tried other ways to get the answer and the for loop was the one that got me the closest...

Answer (score 1):

You are making this too complicated. The function needs to do two things:

1. determine if the length of the input string is a multiple of 3
2. if so, return the length of the input string divided by 3

You were right in assuming that you can use `... % 3 == 0` somehow but you were not applying it correctly. You don't need a `for` loop, which iterates over the individual characters in the string. Just apply it on the length of the string directly.

Regarding 2., even if you had managed to count the characters in the input string, you forgot to divide by 3.

Here's a straightforward solution:

```
def countCodons(DNA):
    if len(DNA) % 3 == 0:  # length is a multiple of 3
        return len(DNA) // 3
    else:
        return False
```

Note that `//` is used to return an integer result, rather than a floating-point result (see [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers)).

Alternatively you could use the [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function which combines the integer division with remainder in one step:

```
def countCodons(DNA):
    count, remainder = divmod(len(DNA), 3)
    if remainder == 0:
        return count
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Or as puzzle: `return not remainder and count`

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you!! Can you just explain why you would divide by 3??

Comment: Because if the input length is 6, the correct result is 2. Codons are groups of 3 characters.

Answer (score -2):

This assertion fails because the return statement is within the loop and only returns the length of the input string, not the count of codons. So, it will always return the length of the input string, even if there are no codons in the input string.

```
assert countCodons("CAATGGG") == False
```

This assertion succeeds because the first element in the input string is not a multiple of 3, so the function returns False.

To fix this issue, the return statement should be outside the loop and return the count of codons. Here's the corrected code:

```
def countCodons(DNA):
  count = 0
  for num in DNA:
    if len(num) % 3 == 0:
      count += 1
  return count if count > 0 else False
```

This code will now correctly return the count of codons in the input string.

Comment: Why are you returning `False` in place of zero, mixing integer and bool return values?  That's one of the bugs that was pointed out in the original code.  Just return `count`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Maybe the requirement is for `False` to represent "invalid input".

Comment: @TomKarzes correct.

Comment: "will now correctly return the count of codons in the input string" - I don't think so.

Comment: @Kamit Thanks so much! I'm still confused on the code itself but when I put it through, the first assertion gives me an error while the 2nd one works. Are you saying its supposed to give me that error since it doesn't work?

Comment: @Adina This solution is completely wrong. If this answer were more eloquent, I'd think it came from ChatGPT.

Comment: If I take away the for loop and do this instead:                                                 def countCodons(DNA):
  if len(DNA) % 3 == 0:
    return len(DNA)
  else:
    return False

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I'm new to Python and am simply trying to figure out this problem for a few days now. I never heard of ChatGPT but I don't believe in getting answer off of the internet or people. If I did, then I would first try to understand it and work with it before moving on. I'm learning to learn. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It could be, but it makes no sense to mix types in this situation.  Zero is a perfectly good unused integer value.  So is -1.  It makes much more sense to always return an integer than to sometimes return an integer and sometimes return a bool.  Doing so is just a bug waiting to happen.